# Porting QTableView from PySide2 to PySide6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside2, pyside6

I have a QTableView with a boolean value in a column, which is interpreted as a checkbox.

In PySide2 when I click on the checkbox, it correctly updates the UI and the stored value. But in PySide6 the same code sample will not work.

Here is the sample code that runs fine on PySide2 but breaks on PySide6:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.model = False

    def rowCount(self, _):
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, _):
        return 1

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return "Test"
    
    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            print("Get data : ",self.model)
            return QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked if self.model else QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            self.model = bool(value)
            print("Set data : ", self.model)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table_model = TableModel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setModel(self.table_model)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    conv = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

After clicking once on the checkbox, self.model is updated, but the UI does not change and keeps sending True when calling setData method.

I looked at the changes between PySide2 and PySide6 ([Porting from PySide2 to PySide6](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/porting_from2.html)) and there's nothing that could trigger this change of behaviour.

**Edit :**

This is a known bug ([PYSIDE-1930](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1930)) that should be fixed in version 6.3.2. Thanks to musicamente for pointing it out.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on PyQt6 on Linux, and the code seems fine to me. Can you try with `self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole])`? Also, with "keeps sending True when calling setData method" do you mean that it prints `True` indefinitely and doesn't stop? That seems just wrong: it shouldn't go on forever, and the value should not be `True` if the item is unchecked.

Comment: Hello, does it also work if you use PySide6 specifically ? I also tried with PyQt6 and this works, but for licensing purposes, I want to use PySide instead of PyQt. What I mean by "keeps sensing True" is that when clicking on the checkbox, it will always send the value True to the setData function, even if the value retrieved by the data function is also True, i.e. multiple clicks don't flip the state of the boolean value.

Comment: I also tried to add the last argument to dataChanged.emit(), but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok, it could be related to this [PYSIDE-1930](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1930) bug. The Qt6 (and python binding) migration has been quite annoying for enums and flags. Try using `self.model = int(value)`.

Comment: It turns out that this issue exists for all enums in Qt, but it should be fixed in PySide6.3.2. I'll use this workaround in the mean time.